# Menu with slidable submenu container

Tags: javascript, css

I have menu defined with UL, LI... up to max one submenu:

```
ul
  li: item 1
  li: item 2
    ul
      li: item 2.1
      li: item 2.2
  li: item 3
    ul
      li: item 3.1
      li: item 3.2
      li: item 3.3
```

What I would like to achieve is to show submenu in a way that "sub menu item container" will slide to the next submenu when clicked. In example above this would mean:

- when user clicks item 2, container with sub items will show
- when user clicks item 3, container with somehow slide/animate/transition from item 2 to item 3, changing sub items

This transition should only happen if sub menu container is already visible... if not, it just shows up next to clicked menu item.

I am not sure how to approach this problem and would like your help on it.
Thank you!

**EDIT:**

This is hover enabled sample, no JS (I know onclick is not supported in CSS, but I can handle this later):
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HDinB

This shows a bottom aligned main menu items. Each main menu item can have sub items (this is only one level deep menu, there will be no more sublevels). Submenu will contain no more than max 9 items which will fit into a box (black box you see). What I want is that subitems apear "in" that box, but when new main item with submenu items is selected this box will slide (if already visible) to the new position and kind of be wrapper for new subitems. Will this be a floating box, or real container, or something 3rd, I don't know because I don't realy know what would be best way to handle this.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? :) And is jQuery allowed?

Comment: CSS with minimal JS would be prefered (no jQuery if possible). I have trouble how to start this.. my original idea is to: 1. show submenu, 2 if new menu is selected (and has a sub menu), transition currently open submenu to the same coordinates of new submenu, 3. fade out/in submenus. But this would require to know when transition ends to start fade in/out.

Comment: ...or, have some kind of absolutely position "background", sliding it back and forth ..

Comment: CSS doesn't have a trigger "on click", so it will only be possible with JS to trigger the click. jQuery will make your life easy, check the answer I provided...

Answer (score 1):

I'm absolute no jQuery expert, and I presume that jQuery is okay for you.

I created you this function. When a submenu is expanded, the class `expand` is assigned to it.

When a link is clicked, the function will check if it has the `expand` class, if so, it will close the submenu. If not, all the other `expand` classes will be closed (if exist) and the submenu will be shown.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">item 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">item 3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 3.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li ul {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li:has(ul) a").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ul = $(this).parent().find('ul');

        if( ul.hasClass('expand') ) {
            ul.removeClass('expand').slideToggle()
        }
        else {
            $('.expand').removeClass('expand').slideToggle();
            ul.addClass('expand').slideToggle();
        }
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/d5eqtehz/).

Hope it suits you, or at least helps you on your way.

Comment: sorry, not realy effect I want... will edit original post to explain in more details

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">item 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">item 3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 3.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<style type="text/css">
ul li{display:inline-block; position:relative;}
ul li ul{display:none;width:100%; position:absolute; white-space: nowrap;margin:0px;padding:0px;top:20px;}
ul li ul li{ display:block;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu li").click(function(){
        $(".menu li ul").slideUp();

        if($(this).find("ul").css("display")=='block')
        {
        $(this).find("ul").slideUp();
        }
        else
        {
        $(this).find("ul").slideDown();
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: sorry, not realy effect I want... will edit original post to explain in more details